# Google Play Android .apk Upload "Failed to run aapt dump badging"

Tags: android, cordova, apk, aapt

It has been almost a year since I last uploaded an App to the Google Play Developer Console (it is a Cordova App that I have signed and zip aligned); follow the same process I have used successfully in the past I am now getting the following error:

> Upload failed
>   Your APK cannot be analyzed using 'aapt dump badging'. Error output:
>   Failed to run aapt dump badging:
>   ERROR: dump failed because assets could not be loaded

What's happening here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was a total noob mistake :

Part of the process of preparing the .apk file is to unzip the .apk created by the Cordova build process, then remove the META-INF folder, then rezip and rename back to an .apk.
The mistake I made was that, when rezipping, I was zipping the FOLDER, rather than zipping the CONTENTS of the folder.
Another way to say that is that I created the Archive one directory too high in the path.

I'm leaving the question and posting the answer in the hope it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause is that we use the 7Zip application to pack the zip package, 
the right solution is use the ZipAlign tool under sdk/tools/ to pack it.